# Proper way to add Angular as a dependency to the npm librarie's list of dependencies

Tags: angular, npm, versioning

I have this small `angular` package on NPM that I keep supporting to be usable in all new versions of `angular`. In my package.json I have added angular to the list of `peerDependencies` to make sure that they are always present in the project, that uses my library:

```
  "peerDependencies": {
     "@angular/animations": "^7.x",
     "@angular/common": "^7.x",
     "@angular/core": "^7.x",
     "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.x",
     "rxjs": "^6.x",
     "typescript": ">=3.1.1 <3.3.0",
     "zone.js": "^0.8.x"
  }
```

But as each new major version of angular is released, the users of my library are constantly experiencing the peer dependencies mismatch warnings being displayed in the console when doing `npm install` like the following:

`npm WARN ng2-go-top-button@7.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/animations@^7.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.`

So my question is: what is the proper way of declaring `angular` as a dependency in my library, so that I don't have to update it each time that new `angular` is released? Maybe I don't need `peerDependencies` at all? But how to make sure, that the project, that uses my library always has all needed libraries in place? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is not about how to install peers. I am asking about a proper way of declaring these dependencies in my library so that my users don't get these warnings each time, that the new angular is released.

Comment: I totally understand it, but my question is, do I even have to make my angular library dependent on these `angular` dependencies? Maybe I just can remove them to not make my users receive warnings each time that the new `angular` major version is released? But in this case, there might be situations when someone installs my lib, but some `angular` dependency is not installed and my lib will not work properly. I want to know, what is a common approach to doing it.

Comment: Yes, and that's what is happening each time that `angular` is released. Each time I have to change it to `7.x`, `8.x`, etc. But I want to break this circle and find another approach of handling this, that's why I have asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out a solution myself because other answers to my question didn't quite fit my problem.

I could have defined `angular` and other dependencies using `"*"` or `"^x.x"` versioning as suggested in the previous answer, but it would be not quite correct because not always the latest version of `angular` is fully compatible with the latest version of `typescript`, that's why setting dependencies versions to `"*"` can possibly cause the project that is dependent on my library to break.

So, finally, I decided to keep my `peerDependencies` list AS-IS and update it every time that new `angular` is released. This way my library will keep the compatible list of dependencies and will not break in development and also will not cause the depending project to break.